# Stripping out all /* */ comments from a paragraph

Tags: java, strings, parsing

I've written this code keeping the following cases in mind and I think I've covered them all. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me determine if I've covered all of them.

Cases I considered:

1. No comments at all
2. `Text /* Text */ Text`
3. `Text /* Text */ Text /* Text */`
4. `Text /* /* Text */ */ Text`
5. `Text /* /* Text */ Text`
6. `Text /* Text`
7. `Text */ Text`

```
private static String stripComments(final String input) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean startSeen = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length();) {
        int moveAheadBy = 1;

        if (startSeen) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == '*' && (i != input.length() - 1 && input.charAt(i + 1) == '/')) {
                startSeen = false;
                moveAheadBy = 2;
            }
        } else {
            if (input.charAt(i) == '/' && (i != input.length() - 1 && input.charAt(i + 1) == '*')) {
                startSeen = true;
                moveAheadBy = 2;
            } else {
                builder.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        i += moveAheadBy;
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: There seem to be (at least) a few cases you haven't considered. For example, (at least if memory serves), a `/*` inside a string literal does not start a comment.

Comment: That is an interesting case.Thank you. Please let me know if you can think of more cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify whether or not nested comments are allowed, but your code trims only the shorter comment. For example, case 4 would yield `Text  Text` with nesting but `Text  */ Text` without. It would be helpful to include some unit tests to demonstrate the intent.

Your solution is pretty straight-forward with only one real complication. I would remove the `moveAheadBy` incrementer and instead perform an extra increment where you're setting `moveAheadBy` to `2`. It's minor, but it removes unnecessary state.

To help with the readability, introduce a variable for the length of the input since it's used in so many places.

Another solution would be to use `indexOf` to seek ahead to the next open/close. The algorithm will still be \$O(n)\$, but the fewer number of `append` calls could add up with very, very long strings. This is more to show an alternate method than to improve on yours.

```
public static String stripComments(final String input) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    int current = 0;
    int end = input.length();

    while (current < end) {
        int nextOpen = input.indexOf("/*", current);
        if (nextOpen == -1) {
            // no more comments
            buf.append(input.substring(current));
            break;
        }
        buf.append(input.substring(current, nextOpen));
        int nextClose = input.indexOf("*/", nextOpen + 2);
        if (nextClose == -1) {
            // final comment not closed
            break;
        }
        current = nextClose + 2;
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Unit Tests**

Now that the method is public, let's add some tests.

```
@Test
public void testNone() {
    assertThat(stripComments("No comments at all"), is("No comments at all"));
}

@Test
public void testSingle() {
    assertThat(stripComments("Single /* foo */ comment"), is("Single  comment"));
}

@Test
public void testDisjoint() {
    assertThat(stripComments("Two /* foo */ disjoint /* bar */ comments"), is("Two  disjoint  comments"));
}

@Test
public void testNested() {
    assertThat(stripComments("Two /* foo /* nested */ baz */ comments"), is("Two  baz */ comments"));
}

@Test
public void testUnclosed() {
    assertThat(stripComments("Unclosed /* foo comment"), is("Unclosed "));
}

@Test
public void testUnopened() {
    assertThat(stripComments("Unopened */ comment"), is("Unopened */ comment"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've dealt with the nested comments /* /* */ */ case like most IDEs do.